# Why do we need Thread.sleep after calling System.gc in JDK native memory usage scenario?

Tags: jvm, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

After my research on the source code implementation details of `System.gc` in Java17 ，i found that `System.gc`will eventually trigger two gc types:

1. **full gc (stop the world)**, when we use SerialGC, ParallelGC, ZGC. and the java thread which invoked the `System.gc` will be blocked until the full gc finished.
2. **concurrent full gc**, when we use G1, Shenandoah with `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent`, and the java thread will return from the `System.gc` soon after trigger concurrent full gc.

## My question

now we discuss the case of full gc ，since java thread will always block in native code(safe point) before full gc is completed,, why does jdk call `Thread.sleep` after calling `System.gc` ?

**do We really need Thread.sleep here ?**

```
public class FileChannelImpl extends FileChannel
{
   private Unmapper mapInternal(MapMode mode, long position, long size, int prot, boolean isSync)
                              throws IOException
   {
            try {
                    // If map0 did not throw an exception, the address is valid
                    addr = map0(prot, mapPosition, mapSize, isSync);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError x) {
                    // An OutOfMemoryError may indicate that we've exhausted
                    // memory so force gc and re-attempt map
                    System.gc();
                    try {
                        // do We really need Thread.sleep here ?
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException y) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    try {
                        addr = map0(prot, mapPosition, mapSize, isSync);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError y) {
                        // After a second OOME, fail
                        throw new IOException("Map failed", y);
                    }
              }

   }
}
```

The java thread will not return from `System.gc` until the full gc is completed，So I think there is no need to call `Thread.sleep` after calling `System.gc(` here

Comment: You cannot rely on `System.gc()` in any way. It may or not perform a collection. Waiting some time _might_ result in the collection being finished but this might not happen (especially if the JVM doesn't even perform one). It is just a suggestion to the JVM. See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#gc()).

Comment: Aside from that, Java should (in most cases) automatically run the GC when the application is out of memory and then attempt the allocation.

Comment: Also it seems like this [has been in the JDK for a long time](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/319a3b994703aac84df7bcde272adfcb3cdbbbf0) so it was written before the new GCs.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying  i have accepted the right answer, you can refer to the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement “*java thread will return from the System.gc soon after trigger concurrent full gc*” contradicts your assumption “*java thread will not return from System.gc until the full gc is completed*”.

*Triggering* a concurrent garbage collection does not imply waiting for its completion.

But regardless of whether the garbage collection completes before returning from `System.gc()` or not, the operation in question is not waiting for the completion of the garbage collection, its waiting for the completion of the *cleaner* which may free existing native memory allocations.

This internal cleaner works similar to [the one that is nowadays publicly available](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html). It runs in a different thread than the garbage collector and waits for the garbage collector to hand over discovered phantom references whose referent became unreachable.

So its crucial to give the cleaner thread enough time, to potentially change from waiting state to running state and execute the cleaning action, i.e. deallocate native memory (or release file mappings).

Comment: Oh my god, how can i missed the cleaner mechanism which is responsible for recycling the native memory behind directByteBuffer.

a greate thanks for your answer , it did really solved my confusion , you are right ,  `Thread.sleep` is not waiting for the completion of the garbage collection, its waiting for the completion of the cleaner which may free existing native memory allocations.

Comment: According to your tips, I also found this behavior in the source code，when gc is completed，hotspot will invoke `VM_GC_Operation::doit_epilogue() `, in this method ,hotspot notify ReferenceHandler thread to run the cleaner ,and the release the native memory